# SQL / REGEX pattern matching

Tags: sql, regex, sql-server-2014

I want to use regex through sql to query some data to return values. The only valid values below returned would be "GB" and "LDN", or could also be "GB-LDN"

```
G-GB-LDN-TT-TEST
G-GB-LDNN-TT-TEST
G-GBS-LDN-TT-TEST
```

As it writes the first GB set needs to have 2 characters specifically, and the LDN needs to have 3 characters specifically. Both sets/groups seperated by an - symbol. I kind of need to extract the data but at the same time ensure it is within that pattern. I took a look at regex but I can't see how to, well it's like substring but I can't see it.

Comment: what RDBMS you are using?

Comment: SQL SERVER 2014

Comment: Would A-AA-AAA be a match too?

Comment: If you really just need 2 or 3 characters which might wrapped in hyphens, _ is a single character wildcard.  You could make LIKE '__' OR '-__' OR '__-' OR '-__-' OR '___' OR '-___' etc.  I can write up something as a better answer if this is the direction you are looking to go

Answer (score 0):

**IF** i undertsand correctly, you could still use of `substring()` function to extract the string parts separated by `-`.

```
select left(parsename(a.string, 3), 2)  +'-'+ left(parsename(a.string, 2) ,3)  from
    (
        select replace(substring(data, 1, len(data)-charindex('-', reverse(data))), '-', '.') [string] from <table>
    ) a
```

As in above you could also define the length of extracted string.

Result :

```
GB-LDN
GB-LDN
GB-LDN
```